# Dictionary array to flat list

Tags: c#, .net, ext.net

Is there a better way (specially using Linq) to return a List/IEnumerable of the IDs in the following json string?

```
string json = "[{\"Id\":38,\"Name\":\"Albert Einstein\",\"Document\":\"845.803.604-51\"},{\"Id\":102,\"Name\":\"Benoit Mandelbrot\",\"Document\":\"657.322.962-20\"},{\"Id\":86,\"Name\":\"Santos-Dumont Aerospace\",\"CpfCnpj\":\"24.195.152/0001-55\"}]";
```

Currently I have:

```
Dictionary<string, string>[] deserializedJSON = Ext.Net.JSON.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(json);

List<decimal> idList = new List<decimal>();

foreach (var item in deserializedJSON)
{
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        if (i.Key == "Id")
            idList.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(i.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `Dictionary` indexer?

Comment: Will all items have IDs?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, it's non-nullable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
idList = deserializedJSON.Select(d => decimal.Parse(d["Id"]))
                         .ToList();
```